# RolesAllowed non constant value

Tags: jakarta-ee, jaas, security-roles

I'm using`@RolesAllowed`. It seems to only work with a constant value. But does a solution exist to use a non constant role in `@RolesAllowed` in Java EE?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to use non-constant names with standard Java EE declarative security. Instead, use `@DeclareRoles` with either `HttpServletRequest.isUserInRole` or `EJBContext.isCallerInRole`.

Comment: How can an instance of `EJBContext` be obtained in a client application like Servlets/JSP/JSF/Swing - AWT...? Using `EJBContext context = (EJBContext) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/EJBContext");`?

Comment: You can only obtain and use an instance of `EJBContext` while in an EJB call. From a servlet/JSP/JSF, you'll have to keep the `HttpServletRequest`, or you'll have to invoke an EJB method for the sole purpose of checking security. (Swing/AWT are client-side programming models, so I don't understand that part of the question.)